# "Referer Header" not sent by "Links" browser

Tags: http, hyperlink, http-referer

Is there a way to force the Links command line browser to send the "Referer Header"?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_(web_browser)

Also, the Lynx browser has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referer is optional and can easily be blocked from a number of browsers (and is a default behavior of many software security products).  If you have any functionality built assuming that data will be passed, you need to rethink your design and implementation.

Comment: So Django has a CSRF(Cross Site Request Forgery) protection which uses that. Also, I believe there are other security purposes for the referrer. How are these practices invalid? Or I should say, what are the alternatives?

Comment: In practical usage, the referer is easily masked or forged.  It should not be counted on for anything other than for general passive tracking, and even that should be considered as suspect data as well.  As far as that Django implementation, it's my opinion (echoed elsewhere: http://osdir.com/ml/django-developers/2010-09/msg00033.html) that any implementation of anything that requires referer headers is essentially broken and going to limit access to some users.

Comment: Tell that to Canonical: the Ubuntu One website requires them.